# How to match with substr and pull documents?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to delete subdocuments by date which matches the first 19 characters. It returns `n: 1 nModified: 0 ok: 1`

Here's my code:

```
Students.update({_id: req.body.student_id}, {
  $project: { shortDate: { $substr: ['$courses.course_enrolling_date', 0, 19] } },
  $pull: {
      courses: {shortDate: req.body.enrolling_date}
    }
  }).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
  })
```

What I'm missing? Thanks for helps

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: I'm just trying to delete a subdocument by matching date.But date format in database in yyyy:mm:ddThh:mm:ss:ms format. But the client side sends date in yyyy:mm:ddThh:mm:ss format. So, miliseconds is trimmed in client side.

And my question is how can I match this short date with the original date in database